# Suspicious phone browser activity

Tags: android, chrome

On a droid Razr M, I used chrome to log in to Gmail instead of the app.  It asked to log in as me on a toast at the bottom of the browser, taking my credentials from somewhere on the phone I assume. When logging out of the mobile Gmail site, a white screen with some text about redirecting appeared briefly, followed by Korean characters.  The URL on exiting is

`http://www.google.co.kr/accounts/Logout2?service=mail&ilo=1&ils=s.KR%2Cyoutube&ilc=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fmu%2F%3Flogin%3D1&zx=`

I've censored the end of this URL where some numbers appear.  Why a Korean domain? Anyway, my question is: Is my mobile browser being hijacked or would it appear that my account has otherwise been compromised in any way?

Comment: Updating this, the issue isn't specific to any browser or a phone.  Clearing caches or using clean devices doesn't seem to have any affect.  Language settings have been checked, application specific passwords exist or strange devices / activity outside of the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

A whois of the www.google.co.kr domain seems to indicate that it is legitimately Google.  Why it was redirecting through there is a bit of a mystery.  I do know that there is a feature on a lot of phones that will us the Google account of the phone.  It is possible that the vendor that wrote the software was Korean and simply used the Google server from their home country to do the redirect.  I'd certainly keep an eye on it, but I don't see how this particular thing could be an attack from what you've described.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow auto login rectangle is Chrome's integration of the **Android Account Manager API**.  OAuth websites can interact with this API by using the `X-Auto-Login` HTTP Response Header.

From my anecdotal evidence it is possible to wind up on a different Google TLD. Other people seem to also have that problem:

- http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=437457
- http://www.justanswer.com/computer/6nf78-google-foreign-language-morning.html